# Hiding links with 0 query value results by php

Tags: php, mysql, show-hide

I have a menu block that contains some links like: Some_link1: 5pcs, Some_link2: 13pcs, Some_link3: 0pcs, Some_link4: 0pcs.
I want to hide link "Some_link" with 0pcs value. I write a code with MySQL query, but it's not working! "Some_link" with 0pcs not hiding but still show  0pcs value.
What i'm doing wrong or what my mistake? I can't understand. Thank you for help.

```
<?
  $resultonline = mysql_query("SELECT count(customers_id) from tbl_customers WHERE active='Y' and saled='N'");
  $resultonshafasaled = mysql_query("SELECT count(customers_id) from tbl_customers WHERE shafa='Y' and saled='Y'");
  $resultonlinenonactive = mysql_query("SELECT count(customers_id) from tbl_customers WHERE active='N' and saled='N'");

  $topmenuNotOnShafa = mysql_result($resultonshafasaled, 0);
  $topmenuonline = mysql_result($resultonline, 0);
  $topmenuoffline = mysql_result($resultonlinenonactive, 0);

  $topmenuonlineText = "Some text : ";
  $topmenuOnShafaText = "Some text 2 : ";
 ?>

<?php if ($topmenuonline!=0): ?><?=$topmenuonlineText;?><?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($topmenuonline!=0): ?><a href="some_link" target="_self"><?=$topmenuonline;?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($topmenuoffline!=0): ?> / <a href="some_link" target="_self"><?=$topmenuoffline;?></a>
<br /><?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($topmenuNotOnShafa!=0): ?>
<span class="saled-warning"><a href="some_link" target="_self" ><?=$topmenuNotOnShafa;?></a></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: chk query manually in phpmyadmin first `SELECT count(customers_id) from tbl_customers WHERE active='Y' and saled='N'`

Comment: @devpro everything is perfect with this query

Comment: you can try to do a a condition for printing the menu like `if($variables != 0){ echo "<a href="menu_item">Hello!</a>";};`

Comment: @RaduRadu Sorry i can't understand you. Please make an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the value of the item is 0 or not and print it only if it is not 0:

Example:

```
 <?php

 $items='0';

 if(isset($items)){
     if($items != 0){
         echo "<a href='non_zero_item.php'>Item from menu (".$items.")";
     } else {
         echo "Oh sorry, there are no items!";
     }
 } else {
     echo "items variable is not declared!";
 }

 ?>
```

In this example you will get the else condition, if you change the variable $items to 1 you will get printed the html code. This is a small test, the variable can be the mysql query result, a manual input like this, etc.

If you dont want to print anything if the value is 0 or not declared, like I understand you want you can do only this:

```
 <?php

 $items='1';

 if(isset($items)){
     if($items != 0){
         echo "<a href='non_zero_item.php'>Item from menu (".$items.")";
     }
 }

 ?>
```

For debuging  I recommend you to use allways the else condition.

Answer (score 1):

use

mysql_num_rows

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows Rows\n";

?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated and close in php 7

Comment: @BruceStackOverFlow Thank you, but i need to hide Some_link=0, but show "Some_link">0

Comment: @ВикторияСикрет <?php if (mysqli_num_rows ($topmenuNotOnShafa) >=1 >
        <p> Show </p>
<?php endif; ?>not work ?

Comment: @BruceStackOverFlow Your code show only blank/white page, even when i add ";" after >=1

Comment: @devpro What do you mean?

Comment: @ВикторияСикрет:first of run your queries manually, in php myadmin, check either query returns result or not. than use `echo  $topmenuNotOnShafa; echo
  $topmenuonline; echo $topmenuoffline;` check what are you getting in these

Comment: @ВикторияСикрет for now use mysql_num_rows instead of mysqli_num_rows shows error?

Comment: @BruceStackOverFlow <?php if (mysql_num_rows ($topmenuNotOnShafa) >=1 ?> <p> Show </p> <?php endif; ?> The same. Blank/white page!

Comment: @devpro "...check either query returns result or not. than use echo $topmenuNotOnShafa; echo $topmenuonline; echo $topmenuoffline; check what are you getting in these..." The query returns results perfectly.

Comment: @ВикторияСикрет sorry replace $topmenuNotOnShaf with $resultonshafasaled

Comment: @BruceStackOverFlow Sorry can't understand you "...sorry use $topmenuNotOnShaf with $resultonshafasaled..."

Comment: @ВикторияСикрет "replace" not "use" ... 
 <?php if (mysql_num_rows ($resultonshafasaled)) >=1 ?> <p> Show </p> <?php endif; ?>

Comment: @BruceStackOverFlow "...<?php if (mysql_num_rows ($resultonshafasaled)) >=1 ?> <p> Show </p> <?php endif; ?>..." Blank/white page.

Comment: @ВикторияСикрет $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($resultonshafasaled);

echo "$num_rows Rows\n"; show ?

Comment: @BruceStackOverFlow Yes. It's show me "1 Rows". But I need a completely different result. I have a list of links in my html table, like: Bra: 5psc, Brasets: 15pcs, Blanket: 0pcs, Towel: 0pcs. I need that "Blanket and Towel hiding from list until they  0 value, after value change to more than 1 they would shown.